# Rails 3 how do I get ActiveRecord::Relation from an array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, pagination

I have a class method on a model class that filters the records based on an attribute that is not part of the schema (but derived from its attributes):

```
def filter(records, some_param)
  records.select { |rec| rec.param > some_param } # param is a derived attribute
end
```

I am calling it from controller.
The problem is I need to paginate the results of this filtering and my project uses 'kaminari' plugin thatr paginates only the ActiveRecord::Relation output.
How do I get ActiveRecord::Relation out of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), then:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```